# Can a superclass call a subclass method from a separate module?

Tags: python, inheritance

If the classes are in separate modules, can the superclass call the subclass method "execute"? I know this can work if they are in the same module.

file2.py

```
import file1
class TestCase(file1.TestBase):

    def execute(self):
        self._pass()
```

file1.py

```
class TestBase:

    def _pass(self):
        print "PASS"

testBase = TestBase()
testBase.execute()
```

Comment: Since you're not actually instantiating `TestCase`, your snippet won't work. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: An object of TestCase is a TestBase, but that relationship is not reciprocal.  If your object is instantiated as a TestBase, it remains blissfully ignorant of its class's later progeny.

Comment: TestBase does not, and should not, know anything about TestCase. That shouldn't work if they are in the same file.

Comment: What about inspecting the stack frames? I want to abstract a test cases functionality to the "TestBase"... Things like (printing, logging, status updates, and even the execution of methods)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have do call it explicitly:

```
from file1 import TestBase

class TestCase(TestBase):   
    def execute(self):
        TestBase.execute(self) # directly
        super(TestCase, self).execute() # or via super() proxy
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be recursive, given that TestBase has not defined a execute attribute?

Comment: Of course not, that would throw `AttributeError` if `TestBase.execute()` is not defined.